# Undefined variable and Undefined index errors

Tags: php

The program I'm working on is supposed to remove dashes, spaces, etc.. from an input box and display the number back to the user.

I am getting an undefined variable and undefined index error in my php code. The errors are on line 35 and 41. I'm guessing the function is out of scope, but I'm not sure.

I made factorial calculator with similar code and it worked fine. I've tried adapting that code to this problem, but I can't get it to work. I don't know why, but I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting an understanding of how php works.

Thanks!

```
<?php
  function getCardNum($cardNum) {

  $ccNum = true;
  if ($_POST) {
     $number = $_POST['cardNum'];
     $number = preg_replace('/[\-\" "]/', '', $number);
     if (is_numeric($number)) {
        $ccNum = true;
     }
     else {
        $ccNum = false;
     }
      return $number;
  }
}

  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Card Validator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Enter your credit card number!:</h3>
    <form method="POST">
      <table border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>Enter numeric character only</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cardNum" id="cardNum" size = "50" /></td>
          <td>
            <?php
              if ($cardNum) {
                 echo '<p style="color:green;">Number is valid</p>';
                 echo '<p style="color:green;">' . getCardNum($_POST['cardNum']) . '</p>';
                    }
                 else {
                 echo '<p style="color:red;">Number contains non-numeric characters!</p><br />';
                 echo '<p style="color:red;">' . getCardNum($_POST['cardNum']) . '</p>';
                       }
                       ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="cardNum" id="cardNum" value="Submit" /></td>
        <td><input type="reset" name="resetButton" id="resetButton" value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>           
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change a few of the conditions, but I think this should work as expected.

The `submit` input was renamed to `submit` because it was causing a conflict.

Added `if (is_numeric($_POST['cardNum'])) {`

and `if ((!is_numeric($_POST['cardNum'])) && (isset($_POST['cardNum']))) {`

```
<?php

function getCardNum() {
$ccNum = true;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     $number = $_POST['cardNum'];
     $number = preg_replace('/[\-\" "]/', '', $number);
     if (is_numeric($number)) {
        $ccNum = true;
     }
     else {
        $ccNum = false;
     }
      return $number;
}
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Card Validator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Enter your credit card number!:</h3>
    <form method="POST" action="">
      <table border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>Enter numeric character only</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cardNum" id="cardNum" size = "50" /></td>
          <td>

<?php


if (is_numeric($_POST['cardNum'])) {

    echo '<p style="color:green;">Number is valid</p>';
    echo '<p style="color:green;">' . getCardNum($_POST['cardNum']) . '</p>';

}
if ((!is_numeric($_POST['cardNum'])) && (isset($_POST['cardNum']))) {


    echo '<p style="color:red;">Number contains non-numeric characters!</p><br />';
    echo '<p style="color:red;">' . getCardNum($_POST['cardNum']) . '</p>';


}
?>

          </td>
        </tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="cardNum" value="Submit" /></td>
        <td><input type="reset" name="resetButton" id="resetButton" value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>           
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working now, but I'm still getting an Undefined index error on line 47. I have been coding all day, I think it's time for a break. Thanks again for the help everyone!

Comment: @KingHippo The condition in line 47 is in a wrong order. Make the `isset` test happen first, like this: `if ((isset($_POST['cardNum'])) && (!is_numeric($_POST['cardNum'])))`

Answer (score 2):

`if ($_POST) {` will always evaluate to true, because `$_POST` superglobal exists all the time. you will have to do more specific test like `if (isset($_POST['cardNum']))`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function before you address keys that you're not sure they exist in an array.

For instance:

```
if (isset($_POST['cardNum'])) {
    echo '<p style="color:green;">Number is valid</p>';
    echo '<p style="color:green;">' . getCardNum($_POST['cardNum']) . '</p>';
}
```